# pandas расчет смещения даты

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

У меня есть 2 df:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'DATE_AND_TIME':['2018-12-05 08:31:23.479', '2018-12-05 08:31:25.654', 
                    '2018-12-05 08:31:27.013', '2018-12-05 08:31:30.004', 
                    '2018-12-05 08:31:32.479', '2018-12-05 08:31:33.079', 
                    '2018-12-05 08:31:34.504', '2018-12-05 08:31:37.729', 
                    '2018-12-05 08:31:38.854', '2018-12-05 08:31:40.654'],
   'DELAY':[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2],
   'CUR':['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD', 'EUR']
})
d1['DATE_AND_TIME'] = d1['DATE_AND_TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
   'CUR':['USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR'], 
   'DATE':['2018-12-04','2018-12-06','2018-12-09','2018-12-11',
           '2018-12-03','2018-12-07','2018-12-09','2018-12-11']
})
d2['DATE'] = d2['DATE'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

мне необходимо определить дату со смещением в d1, исходная дата в колонке DATE_AND_TIME, исходное смещение в DELAY. Я нахожу исходную дату со смещением:

```
d1['PRE_ISD'] = d1['DATE_AND_TIME'] + pd.to_timedelta(d1.DELAY, unit='D')
```

дальше если для данной CUR есть DATE, попадающая в интервал между DATE_AND_TIME и PRE_ISD, то PRE_ISD надо добавить еще 1 день. И добавлять пока между DATE_AND_TIME и PRE_ISD не останется ровно DELAY дней не имеющихся в d2 для данной CUR.

То что я ожидаю увидеть на выходе:

```
  CUR            DATE_AND_TIME  DELAY         ISD
0  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:23.479      1  2018-12-06
1  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:25.654      2  2018-12-08
2  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:27.013      2  2018-12-08
3  USD  2018-12-05 08:31:30.004      3  2018-12-10
4  USD  2018-12-05 08:31:32.479      2  2018-12-08
5  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:33.079      2  2018-12-08
6  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:34.504      3  2018-12-10
7  USD  2018-12-05 08:31:37.729      2  2018-12-08
8  USD  2018-12-05 08:31:38.854      2  2018-12-08
9  EUR  2018-12-05 08:31:40.654      2  2018-12-08
```

заранее спасибо

ps.

лучшее из того, что у меня получилось:

```
d1['PRE_ISD'] = d1['DATE_AND_TIME'] + pd.to_timedelta(d1.DELAY, unit='D')

def calc_isd(x,isd):    
    c_isd = isd[(isd.CUR == x.CUR) & (isd.DATE > x.DATE_AND_TIME )].sort_values(by=['DATE'])
    for c in c_isd.itertuples():
        if c.DATE <= x.PRE_ISD:
            x.PRE_ISD = x.PRE_ISD + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')
        else:
            break
    return x
d1['ISD'] = d1.apply(lambda x: calc_isd(x,d2), axis=1)['PRE_ISD'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
del d1['PRE_ISD']
```

правда всего на 63к строк работает целых 3 минуты, если кто-то подскажет как сие оптимизировать буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Можете пояснить эту часть: `"И добавлять пока между DATE_AND_TIME и PRE_ISD не останется ровно DELAY дней не имеющихся в d2 для данной CUR."`? Может быть на примере одной-двух строк... В текущей формулировке - это не очень понятно... Почему во второй строке `2018-12-08`, а не `2018-12-07`?

Comment: на примере 2 строки с 2018-12-05 первоначальное смещение (+2) 2018-12-07, но если мы посмотрим на d2 то для EUR есть дата 2018-12-07, которая добавит 1 день к смещению, конечной даты не должно быть в d2

Comment: все ещё не понимаю алгоритм... А почему `2018-12-10` в строке с индексом `3`? Ведь `2018-12-05 + 3 days = 2018-12-08` и запись с такой датой для `USD` отсутствует в `d2`

Comment: на 3 строке  с 2018-12-05 первоначальное смещение (+3) 2018-12-08, для USD в d2 есть дата 2018-12-06, которая попадает в между 2018-12-05 и 2018-12-08 и вызывает смещение до 2018-12-09. Но 2018-12-09 не может быть конечной датой, тк для USD она есть в d2, а значит нужно сделать еще 1 смещение на день. 2018-12-10 нет в d2 для USD, значит оставляем ее.

Comment: а почему в первой итерации вы выбираете из `d2` `2018-12-06`, а не `2018-12-09`? Похоже вам придется писать решение с циклом... Не вижу как здесь можно использовать векторизированный подход

Comment: потому что в 1 итерации 2018-12-09 не попадает в интервал между 2018-12-05 и 2018-12-08, а 2018-12-06 попадает, а на 2 итерации 2018-12-09 уже попадает